# Sound laws in Balto-Slavic and Slavic changes

Tags: proto-indo-european, sound-change, slavic-languages

What are the regular sound laws that explain the modern form of the words in baltic and slavic languages?
I am aware of the centum/satem separation, which already helps to identify a lot of cognates in modern slavic languages ("srdce", for heart, for example, and similar things), but other than that I have not found, say, something analogous to Grimm's and Verner's laws in Germanic languages (the Germanic consonant shifts).  I read about Hirt's law and about the controversial Winter's law in wikipedia, but I still feel like there has to be much more. For example, one thing that anyone studying a slavic language notices very soon is the ammount of palatalized consonanst (the division between "hard" and "soft" consonants). Are there regular sound change laws explaining how all these "new" sounds arose in this family of languages?

Comment: This is, I fear, too broad to be answerable as it stands. Balto-Slavic absolutely revels in sound laws. There are what seems like hundreds of named sound laws just relating to Balto-Slavic accentuation alone. So the very simple answer is “yes, there are”, but a full answer would have to include myriad sound laws, which is just too broad.

Comment: Could you mention at least a few representative ones or at least send some reference(s)?

Comment: I’m no great shakes at Balto-Slavic (or indeed at law names; I’m always getting the names mixed up!), but there is at least Dybo’s Law, Ruki (shared with Indo-Iranian and Armenian) and Pedersen’s Law. A lot of the developments of any branch (including Balto-Slavic) are of course not named, just noted as developments; for example, I don’t recall the merger of _*o_ and _*a_ being named after anyone.

Comment: I think you may want to take a look at Chapter 18 Balto-Slavic in Fortson 2010 *Indo-European language and culture*

Comment: also see Kim 2018 *The phonology of Balto-Slavic* https://www.academia.edu/382815/The_phonology_of_Balto-Slavic or Collins 2018 *The phonology of Slavic* https://www.degruyter.com/view/book/9783110542431/10.1515/9783110542431-002.xml (paywall)

Comment: Take a look at [Slavic Palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavic_palatalization) (there are several laws involved). It's one of the most characteristic features of Slavic.